# Timedoctor2 not open in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: crash, 22.04

Timedoctor2 is not opening. It crashes with the following error output:

[image: Timedoctor2 error output]

```
[Main] ERROR sfproc.webview - The render process was terminated "satusCode = 159 " "status = \"Crashed\" " "url = QUrl(\"\") "
```

Comment: I heard back from their support that it's not currently supported on Ubuntu 22.04. They say that they're working on it though.

Answer (score 6):

Try to run in the terminal:

```
export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1
```

And open the time running:

```
~/timedoctor2/timedoctor2
```

Comment: What does this do and why does it help? Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1411940/edit) your question to add some more details and help future visitors be able to recognize if this answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the check above *Use system proxy*. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04:

1. Exit from the top right corner by right-clicking.
2. From a terminal run:

   ```
   export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1
   ```
3. From a terminal run:

   ```
   timedoctor2
   ```

   and keep the terminal running.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once installation finished, exit timedoctor
2. Edit below file in your favorite editor

> vim ~/.local/share/applications/timedoctor2.desktop

3. Modify **exec** parameter and add below environment variable

> exec=env QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1 env QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1 /home/HOME_DIR/timedoctor2/timedoctor2

4. Edited file looks like below.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=0.9.4
Name=Time Doctor 2
Comment=Run Time Doctor 2
Icon=/home/HOME_DIR/timedoctor2/timedoctor2.png
Exec=env QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1 /home/HOME_DIR/timedoctor2/timedoctor2
Terminal=false
Path=/home/HOME_DIR/timedoctor2
Categories=Development
```